# Name of the Rayleigh–Taylor demonstrator toy

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology, stability

There is a common physics "toy" consisting of two liquids sealed into the space between two sheets of plexiglass. When turned upside down, it demonstrates the [Rayleigh–Taylor instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Taylor_instability).

I cannot find the name of this device. All of my googles on the topic turn up unrelated devices or general information on R-T, Google Images shows nothing.

Does anyone have a pointer to one of these?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any name for this device, but you can find something related here: https://instructional-resources.physics.uiowa.edu/demos/2c4090-shock-wave-fronts-rayleigh-taylor-instability-0.

Comment: The one on the left is what I recall. It seems frustratingly difficult to fine.

Comment: You could write them an e-mail. To me the device looks self-made. I am not sure if this device is for commercial sale anywhere.